# Android studio won't change string

Tags: android, android-studio

In my `strings.xml` file I had this string:

```
<string name="lets_do_this">Let's Do This</string>
```

This gave me an error of:

> Error:(897) Apostrophe not preceded by \ (in Let's Do This)

So I changed the string to this:

```
<string name="lets_do_this">Let\'s Do This</string>
```

But every time I build the project, the string keeps changing back to the first version for some reason and I keep getting that error without the ability to change the string. Why is this happening?

Comment: Are you sure you are changing the strings.xml and not the build/intermediates strings.xml ? ps : forward slash ( \ ) is not the same as backslash ( \ )

Comment: The mistake between the forward and backslash is in the question itself and was my mistake in writing it. I did a backslash in the code itself. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it changes back, sounds like you changed the strings xml file that is located within the `build` folder, but you need to edit your own within `res/values` of the app module.

Answer (score 2):

If you have an apostrophe (') in your string, you must either escape it with a backslash (\') or enclose the string in double-quotes ("").

see
[Formatting and Styling - String Resources](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#FormattingAndStyling)

```
<string name="lets_do_this">"Let's Do This"</string>
```